# wilcox_test returns the wrong U value for MWU

Tags: r, statistics

when I use wilcox.test to run a Mann Whitney U non-parametric test, the W value that is returned is the larger of the two U values. That seems strange to me, as the MWU test uses the smaller of the two U values as the test statistic, so I would want to see that value to report the data. Below is an example. If I run the code in R, the W value is listed at 214.

```
wilcox.test(disp ~ am, data = mtcars)
```

But if I calculate this using another program or website (I like this calculator: https://www.socscistatistics.com/tests/mannwhitney/), I get that the two U values are 33 and 214. We then use 33 to check against the critical value and would report that value.

Is there any package that calculates the MWU in a more user-friendly way where it shows the correct/smaller U value as the test statistic? I tried rstatix's version and that does the same thing. Also, does anyone know why this would be the default behavior? It seems counterintuitive.

Answer (score 3):

If you have your data in wide format, use `wilcox.test` in its two-argument format, rather than its formula format.  Switching the arguments will provide the two `U` values.

Pivot `mtcars` to wide:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

mtcars_wide<- mtcars %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "am", values_from = "disp", names_prefix = "am_")
```

Use the two-argument format for `wilcox.test` to get each `U`:

```r
mtcars_wide %$% wilcox.test(am_0, am_1, data = .)$statistic # 214

mtcars_wide %$% wilcox.test(am_1, am_0, data = .)$statistic # 33
```

Note: It doesn't matter how you move the data to wide format - I use tidyverse packages but they're not necessary.  The point is that you can get each `U` by swapping the column names when you run the test.

Comment: I think it may also be worth commenting that neither U value is "correct"; `stats::wilcox.test.default` shows that R consults different tails appropriately: `p <- if (STATISTIC > (n.x * n.y/2)) pwilcox(STATISTIC -  1, n.x, n.y, lower.tail = FALSE) else pwilcox(STATISTIC,  n.x, n.y)`

Answer (score 1):

*Note* The `wilcox.test` function in the stats package does not follow the same convention as `t.test` and reverse the sign of the test statistic based on the sign of the grouped differences.  It calculates a different test statistic estimate with the same significance level. The sign of the *V* test statistic will always be positive since it is **the sum of the positive signed ranks**.

Consider manually reordering your factor levels if you want the other number mtcars example

```r
wilcox.test(disp ~ am, data = mtcars)


#>  Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction
#> 
#> data:  disp by am
#> W = 214, p-value = 0.0005493
#> alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am, levels = c(1,0))
wilcox.test(disp ~ am, data = mtcars)


#>  Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction
#> 
#> data:  disp by am
#> W = 33, p-value = 0.0005493
#> alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```